# Can IntelliJ debug two war files on the same instance of tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I have two web applications that each produce a war file. Sometimes I need to run and debug both of them at the same time. The way I accomplish this today is to run Project A on tomcat 6 at port 8080, and Project B on tomcat 7 at port 8181.

I have IntelliJ setup so that tomcat points to the exploded war file in the target directory. Both projects use Maven (i.e. pom based). **Is there a way to run/debug both of them at the same time from tomcat 7?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the IDEA `Tomcat Run/Debug Configuration`, `Deployment` tab you can configure multiple artifacts to be deployed on the same Tomcat instance.

If you want to deploy them to different Tomcats, create 2 Tomcat Run/Debug configurations and use them instead. You can run multiple configurations at the same time.